# How to use a variable in bash when the folder name contains spaces?

Tags: bash

I'm working on my dotfiles scripts, and am creating a `restore.sh` script to copy preferences, folders, etc. after a clean install.

I've created a check to see if a drive name was entered as an argument, and if not to use a default drive. But!... the default drive has spaces in the filename.

So I've created a test script to copy a file from `/Users/tim/My Folder/file.txt` to `~/Desktop/file.txt`

```sh
if [[ $# -eq 0 ]];
    then
    dir="My\ Folder"
else
    dir=$1
fi

options=(-a -v -h -W --progress --compress-level=0)

rsync "${options[@]}" "/Users/tim/$dir/file.txt" "~/Desktop/file.txt"
```

That doesn't work, so I've been playing with variations on this

```sh
from="/Users/tim/$dir/file.txt"
to="~/Desktop/file.txt"
options=(-a -v -h -W --progress --compress-level=0 $from $to)
rsync "${options[@]}"
```

But I continually get the following error

```
rsync: link_stat "/Users/tim/My\ Folder/file.txt" failed: No such file or directory (2)
```

I've been reading up on this and thought arrays were the way to add spaces in variables, but so far nothing I'm trying is working.

Comment: Have you tried removing the backslash in `dir="My\ Folder"`? It shouldn't be there. Also consider adding quotation marks around the other option: `dir="$1"`

Comment: @TedLyngmo If I remove the backlash I get `/Users/tim/Desktop/Folder/file.txt`

Comment: If you remove the backslash end do `echo "$dir"` - what do you see?

Comment: `"~/Desktop/file.txt"` is wrong too. `~` will not be expanded to your home directory if put in quotation marks.

Comment: `My Folder`. And if I replace the `rsync` command with `echo` I get `-a -v -h -W --progress --compress-level=0 /Users/tim/My Folder/file.txt ~/Desktop/file.txt`. So it all looks great when I echo, but not when I run the command. However, on a Mac that backslash does need to be there

Comment: If bash on a Mac requires that backslash, I think that bash version is buggy. The `rsync` line should probably be `rsync "${options[@]}" "/Users/tim/$dir/file.txt" "${HOME}/Desktop/file.txt"` (and no backslash in `dir` - it becomes a part of the filename). Did you also put quotation marks around the other option, making it `dir="$1"`?

Comment: @TedLyngmo You're right, I actually didn't need the backslash (I just upgraded to Big Sur) and what you gave fixed it. The problem was the tilde. Adding `${HOME}` fixed it. If you like, post that as an answer and I'll mark it solved. Thank you!

Comment: If that's the problem this should be closed as duplicate, not answered.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy It had two problems but I guess it's possible to add the other (the backslash thingy) as a duplicate too if it exists. Should I remove the answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if [[ $# -eq 0 ]];
then
    dir="My Folder" # this shouldn't have a backslash, it becomes a part of the filename
else
    dir="$1"        # this should have quotation marks around it in case of globbing
fi
```

The `~` in `"~/Desktop/file.txt"` will not be expanded to the home directory. Use `${HOME}` instead:

```
rsync "${options[@]}" "/Users/tim/$dir/file.txt" "${HOME}/Desktop/file.txt"
```